# Is sorting within a Map definition considered a bad practice?

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

In my application there are multiple areas which require a list of query results sorted by the same field.

So I have defined a static index like this:

```
public sealed class BlogPosts_OrderedByPublishDateDesc : AbstractIndexCreationTask<BlogPost>
{
    public BlogPosts_OrderedByPublishDateDesc()
    {
        Map = blogPosts => from blogPost in blogPosts
                           orderby blogPost.PublishedOn descending
                           select new
                           {
                            blogPost.PublishedOn
                           };
    }
```

}

This works, but sorting **within** an Map definition somehow sounds like a bad idea.

So, far I haven't found any evidence for or against.

What's the recommended approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorting on the map is a noop, it has no affect on the actual order of returned items.
You need to order during the query to make this happen

Answer (score 0):

Order seems like a fairly trivial reason to create an individual class.

Unless you're adding some other kind of unique functionality to the class that requires a specific order, I would say leave it out of the class and allow the caller to order the data however they require.

Comment: According to official user group, this this is the recommended approach: "[static index] is less likely to be stale at first runs". http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/28023a7dd69e005f?fwc=1 . I want to know whether sorting *within* a Map definition is considered bad for any reason?